# Why Entity Framework is not generating AspNetUserRoles Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I know this is little basic question.But no having Idea about this so asking. Trying to fetch the AspNetUserRoles in DAL layer using Entity framework. But somehow VS2013 not generating model for AspNetUserRoles table. Why?

Comment: Why 1 down? please guide.

Answer (score 1):

To generate Asp.Identity Models your DB context class has to derive from IdentityDbContext class.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
}
```